# How to list all controls which can receive focus, respond to hotkeys and mouse clicks on a visible form in Delphi and FreePascal?

Tags: delphi, focus, freepascal, hotkeys, enumerate

I am looking for a feature where I can use the keyboard to navigate to or activate any actionable control on a form in one shot.

For those not acquainted with ace-jump in Emacs, or browser addons like Tridactyl, Vimium and Surfing Keys, you press a hotkey and all clickable or reachable items are overlaid with key pairs that enable you click a link or jump to an edit control.

[image: browser counterpart]

Comment: Emm.. do you mean Controls[], <Tab> jumping and TabStop property of controls?

Comment: Also the accelerator key marked  with &?

Comment: Nowadays Windows installation don't [underline access keys](https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Underline-Shortcut-Keys.png) by default. Having all possible actions in one list is an impossible feature - it must be done by yourself - is that what you wanted and don't know how? Your Q title differs drastically from the Q text.

Comment: @Mbo All that and including accelerator keys

Comment: @DelphiCoder Those too. Anything on a form that triggers an action or an accept input.

Comment: That screenshot is not a "_form_" - that's a website. Wanting a feature that is rendered through a web browser engine on Windows' native GUI is jumping between galaxies. How about first finding a tool which achieves this for windows in Windows at all before starting to think about coding it? Why not linking all your products which you mention? The internet works through links, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows such a feature has been called [**accelerator** key](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Specifying_Accelerator_Keys_and_Keyboard_Shortcuts) in the past:

> Accelerator keys enable the user to access a menu command from the keyboard by pressing <kbd>Alt+</kbd> the appropriate letter, indicated in your code by the preceding ampersand. The letter after the ampersand appears underlined in the menu.
>
> To specify an accelerator, add an ampersand in front of the appropriate letter. For example, to add a Save menu command with the <kbd>S</kbd> as an accelerator key, type `&Save`. Keyboard shortcuts enable the user to perform the action without using the menu directly, by typing in the shortcut key combination.

Nowadays Windows itself and [web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key) call them [**access** keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/access-keys):

> An access key is a combination of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and one or more alphanumeric keys—sometimes called a mnemonic—typically pressed sequentially, rather than simultaneously.